# Magento writing to tmp/magento directory

Tags: magento-1.7, session, permissions, redis, memcached

The site started throwing exceptions on both the front & backend. After disabling redis, memcached & the full page cache and reverting to using files for sessions, the site seems to function correctly. However, when running the following code:

```
$var_dir = Mage::getModel('core/config')->getVarDir(); 
echo $var_dir;
```

Magento prints out

```
/tmp/magento/var
```

I believe this is what was causing the original issue. I read the following article -
[Stop Magento Writing to /tmp](http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/stop-magento-writing-to-tmp.html) - which mentions:

> Magento itself chooses to try /tmp/magento/ if the var/ folder is not writable.

I checked the permissions on the folder & they are set correctly to 755 (I even tried changing this to 2755) & the owner is also correctly set. Even though that is the case, Magento still doesn't see said directory as writeable. (For interest sake, nor does it see the `app/etc/modules` directory as writeable.

I've spoken with the host & we attempted to stop PHP & restart apache after removing the `/tmp/magento` directory, but Magento just created it again.

Has anybody seen this behaviour before? How can I correct it so that Magento starts writing to the correct webroot `var/` directory?

Comment: Did you clear the cache from `/tmp/magento/var` after changing the permissions to `var` ?

Comment: @Marius, no I didn't. I'm going to try that now & report back. Thanks

Comment: @Marius, I've tried clearing the cache in-between and unfortunately Magento simply re-creates the `tmp/magento` directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a push in the right direction.
Take a look at the method `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options::getVarDir()`

```
public function getVarDir()
{
    //$dir = $this->getDataSetDefault('var_dir', $this->getBaseDir().DS.'var');
    $dir = isset($this->_data['var_dir']) ? $this->_data['var_dir']
        : $this->_data['base_dir'] . DS . self::VAR_DIRECTORY;
    if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
        $dir = $this->getSysTmpDir().DS.'magento'.DS.'var';
        if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
            throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Unable to find writable var_dir');
        }
    }
    return $dir;
}
```

obviously for you the first `if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {` fails while trying to create the `var` folder in your magento instance if that one does not exist.
So if your folder exists, check why that call does not recognize it and if it doesn't exist check why it can't create it.

Maybe the `var` folder is a simlink and php does not recognize it as a folder (this shouldn't happen, but I'm just writing what ever I can think of).  So try debugging `createDirIfNotExists` from the same class I mentioned above.

Comment: Is the dead code really part of the actual source? (first line of the function body). I wonder that this was not catched by a source-code scanner in QA.

Answer (score 0):

cd in your site root path and run chmod -R 777 var